# How to add Facebook share button in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, extjs

I got the code for a "share" button on facebook along with instructions:

> Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

> Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://recovery.twindb.com" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

So I'm trying to add that to an ExtJS web app.

I have a view, where I added `fb-root` container and `fbxxx` where I would like to place the button:

```
Ext.define('recovery.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
...
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    id: 'fb-root',
    width: 50,
    height: 20,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        id: 'fbxxx'
    }]
}]
listeners: {
    beforerender: function (container) {
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        var html = '<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://recovery.twindb.com" data-layout="button_count"></div>';
        var ctn = container.down('#fbxxx');
        console.log(ctn);
        ctn.update(html);
    }
```

This however doesn't work. No errors in the console, but no button is shown up.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the JavaScript SDK in your html file.

(You'll might be able to use [`Ext.mixin.Mashup`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Mashup) for loading the JavaScript SDK too)

A working example:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ule

Comment: Great answer! Didn't know about this mixin :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the SDK to put a share button. Here's how:

1. Go to [FB Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)
2. Fill the form of *Share Button Configurator* and click *"Get Code"*
3. On top of the windows that has opened, click on *IFrame*
4. Copy that code and paste it after an "html:" property anywhere inside your app. For example:

   `{
       width: 64,
       height: 18,
       margin: '0 11 0 0',
       html: 'here goes the IFrame code'
   }`